# rxjs-redux observable not compiling after installing, issue with node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

After two days of fighting with the bare installation and attempting to implement the simplest of examples following a guide of Egghead.

I am having trouble with node modules finding any of its components for some reason.

Epics Index:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {combineEpics} from 'redux-observable';

function loadStoriesEpic(action$) {
    return action$
        .do(action => console.log(action))
        .ignoreElements();
}

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(loadStoriesEpic);
```

My actual error on console that doesn't compiles.

> RROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/Observable' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs'  @
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js 6:9-42  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/ActionsObservable.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'rxjs-compat/Subject' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs'  @
>   ./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js 6:9-39  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/createEpicMiddleware.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/from.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/observable/from' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/observable'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/from.js 6:9-47  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/ActionsObservable.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/merge.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/observable/merge' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/observable'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/merge.js 6:9-48  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/combineEpics.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/observable/of' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/observable'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.js 6:9-45  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/ActionsObservable.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/filter.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/operator/filter' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/operator'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/filter.js 6:9-47  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/operators.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/operator/map' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/operator'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js 6:9-44  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/createEpicMiddleware.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs-compat/operator/switchMap' in
>   '/Users/laxosceles/react-portfolio-solstice/node_modules/rxjs/operator'
>   @ ./node_modules/rxjs/operator/switchMap.js 6:9-50  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/createEpicMiddleware.js  @
>   ./node_modules/redux-observable/lib/esm/index.js  @ ./src/index.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./src Child html-webpack-plugin for
>   "index.html":
>                                      Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>       db7499f085244c16cc8c.hot-update.json  44 bytes          [emitted]
>        + 1 hidden asset
>       Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html

I do not think it has something to do with the issue, but yet I am going to say it , I recently added Yarn to my project and now I installed it with "yarn add" I do not think it should be an issue given the dependency shows in my package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you are using `rxjs v6` and `redux-observable v.0.x` because I see there are imports errors (that's what has been the breaking change in rxjs v6 and `redux-observable v.0.x` is compatible with rxjs5).

You need to [upgrade redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/MIGRATION.html) or downgrade `rxjs` to version 5.

A [github issue](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/491).

Comment: it seems like that redux-observable version is at alpha though

Comment: Yep, it is an API has changed slightly. You can then downgrade `rxjs` to v5 and it will be easier to follow tutorial.